# Как запустить три команды ffmpeg на Linux одной командой?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Как запустить эти три (или более) команды одной командой?

ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i "{source-1}" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -c:a libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -c:v copy -threads 2 -bufsize 512k -f flv "{rtmps://link-1/key}"

ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i "{source-2}" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -c:a libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -c:v copy -threads 2 -bufsize 512k -f flv "{rtmps://link-2/key}"

ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i "{source-3}" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -c:a libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -c:v copy -threads 2 -bufsize 512k -f flv "{rtmps://link-3/key}"

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514

Comment: А зачем? Одна команда будет работать менее надёжно чем три

Comment: @КириллМалышев всеравно будет 3 команды

Comment: Используй ffmpeg-server

Comment: @eri А можешь чуть подробнее про ffmpeg-server касаемо моего вопроса?

Comment: там в конфиге указываешь несколько входов, несколько выходов и запускай